# Получить два числа из строки C++

Tags: c++, строки

Есть строка формата `"123,456,123,23,789,67"`. 6 чисел разделены запятыми.
Необходимо получить 2 последних числа в переменные типа `int`.

Проблема решается легко при помощи `sscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buf[] = "123,456,123,23,789,67";
    int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, p1, p2;

    sscanf(buf, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &a1, &a2, &a3, &a4, &p1, &p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос: Как решить эту проблему при помощи iterator'ов и методов класса `string`?

Comment: Вы эту строку от пользователя считываете? Или заранее написана?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для начала можно разбить строку на подстроки. Вариантов реализаций этого (фактически - метод `split`) - вагон и маленькая тележка. Приведу один, совсем примитивный, для примера:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string & s, char delimeter)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delimeter))
    {
       tokens.push_back(item);
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Соответственно,

```
std::string s("123,456,123,23,789,67");
std::vector<std::string> tokens = split(s, ',');
```

Ну а что делать с получившимся вектором - уже творчески :)

Comment: Спасибо! Всё оказалось достаточно просто и очевидно.

Comment: @Pink Tux: А почему именно `std::vector` может лучше `std::forward_list`?

Answer (score 3):

Если требуется получить несколько последних чисел, то и читать логично с конца, чтобы не обрабатывать потенциально лишние данные.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string buf = "123,456,123,23,789,67";

    size_t ppos = std::string::npos;
    do 
    {
        size_t pos = buf.find_last_of(',', ppos - 1);
        int v = stoi(buf.substr(pos + 1, ppos - (pos + 1)));
        std::cout << v << "\n"; // Используем `v` по назначению
        ppos = pos;
    }
    while( ppos != std::string::npos );
}
```

<kbd>[Посмотреть результат](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kaznmPOFZH12qfGJ)</kbd>

После получения нужного количества данных, цикл можно прервать.

Comment: `stoi()` --  это начиная с С++11

Comment: @avp да. И на календаре у меня уже 2016. А у Вас? :)

Comment: У меня тоже. Только  вот (по крайней мере в Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (не говоря уж о более ранних (14.04 LTS будет на поддержке до 19-го))) для g++ даже в новой версии 5.3.1 -std= по умолчанию --    `gnu++98
           gnu++03
               GNU dialect of -std=c++98.  This is the default for C++ code.` Так что даже 11-й, будет всюду совсем актуальным еще не скоро.

Comment: @avp передать ключик компилятору не такая большая проблема. Ну, если только уж для совсем ленивых :) Вот если бы поддержки `c++11` не было вовсе, тогда был бы уже другой разговор.

Comment: Ну, вот чтобы ключик добавляли, я и написал комментарий.